# disconnect Twilio video

Tags: video, twilio

Hello I successfully started a video call but when I disconnect it the camera led indicator is still ON. how can I completely disconnect the call?

```
Video.createLocalVideoTrack().then(track => {
        var localMediaContainer = document.getElementById('preview');
        localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
    });

Video.connect(response.data, { name: 'room', video: {width: 600} }).then(room => {
    activeRoom = room;
});

$('#disconnect').on('click', () => {
    activeRoom.disconnect();
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To disconnect your local user's video and microphone input you can [stop the tracks](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/LocalTrack.html#stop__anchor). To do so, before you leave the room, call

```
activeRoom.localParticipant.tracks.forEach(function(track) { 
  track.stop()
});
```

That should force the tracks to stop and the LED to go off.

Just as a note, the LED is only on to say that the camera is in use. When you disconnect from a room the media stops streaming to the room.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: hey. thanks for your message. I´m still seeing the LED ON is that because I also have createLocalVideoTrack()? how to disconnect that too? (updated question to reflect this part)

Comment: Possibly. You should be able to call `stop` on that track object that you created with `createLocalVideoTrack`. Try that and let me know how you get on.

Comment: hey philnash what If I want to enable the video again? track.stop() doesn´t exist. what will be the recommended way to stop sending video and then resuming sending video. thanls!

Comment: If you want to start and stop the video at will then you should use [`enable`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/LocalTrack.html#enable__anchor) and [`disable`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/LocalTrack.html#disable__anchor). These methods stop you sending the tracks, but don't stop the media stream entirely. If you used `stop` then you have to get a new media stream and renegotiate the connection. With enable and disable the connection remains.

Comment: @philnash I have the same issue but with version 2 of twilio video, Error is `track.stop is not a function`.I also tried `room.localParticipant.removeTrack(track)` and the same error occur `removeTrack.stop is not a function`

Comment: This code works for version 1. In version 2 [`room.localParticipant.tracks`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.0.0-beta2/docs/LocalParticipant.html) returns a `Map` of `LocalTrackPublications`. You can call [`unpublish` on the `LocalTrackPublication`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.0.0-beta2/docs/LocalTrackPublication.html#unpublish__anchor) which will unpublish the track from the room, or you can call `track` on the `LocalTrackPublication` to get the original track and call `stop` on that.

Comment: If you have problems like this, particularly with a new version of the SDK, I recommend checking the API documentation: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.0.0-beta2/docs/index.html

Comment: @philnash How  do I re enable the connection after using stop() ?

Comment: Once you stop a track you can't restart it, you would need to request access to the camera/mic again. If you just want to disable a track and later enable it again, you can call [`disable` and then `enable`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.7.0/docs/LocalVideoTrack.html#disable__anchor).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. The 2.0 SDK says that after **stopping** the tracks they should be **unpublished**:

```js
const mediaTracks = [localVideoTrack, localAudioTrack];
const tracks = [...mediaTracks, localDataTrack];

mediaTracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
room.localParticipant.unpublishTracks(tracks);
mediaTracks.forEach(track => track.detach());
```

Comment: How are you reconnecting then ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where the camera remain connected even after the call ended. I talked to Twilio and found out in version 2 of the software there is a bug and Twilio is now working on it. If you want to have the camera to disconnect please use version one of the software.

You can find a working example of version one at url: https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js  I have used this design for my application and it works.